# Change Split Column Name and catch data from tables

Tags: python

I have this data in plain text format and they are blocks. There are multiple blocks within a single file. And all blocks are in same format.

```
FIRST  LAST    ADDRESS       UserID
NAME   NAME    POSTAL CODE   Category
RAM    Shyaam  101 Street    11
Batchid:123    44600         Student
```

How do I convert this data into the following format:

```
FIRST NAME:RAM, LAST NAME:Shyaam,ADDRESS:101 Street, POSTAL CODE:44600, UserID:11, Category:Student, Batchid:123
```

Comment: Your Above data is a `dataframe`,`csv file` , `text file` or what?

Comment: It is unclear what you're asking for. Is this all the data you need to parse? If not, is it always in the same format? Please provide more information on the problem being solved, and include anything you have so far.